# How to use jquery with click function

Tags: jquery, html, click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cont6').hide();
$('#cont5').hide();
$('#cont4').hide();
$('#cont3').hide();
$('#cont2').hide();
$('#cont1_a').click(function () {
    $('#cont1').hide();
    $('#cont2').fadeIn(1000, function () {
        if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) == 7) {
            this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
        }
    });
    return false;
}); });
```

I have got another hyper link which needs to do the same function as above when clicked how can i integrate  both the click function in it so that i don't need to duplicate the code, should i use AND operator for it , any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add a class to them both and bind that way, or do this:

```
$('#cont1_a, #cont1_b').click(...);
```

You could also move the function out of the handler definition and give it a name, then bind this way:

```
$("#cont1_a").click(functionName);
$("#cont1_b").click(functionName);

function functionName() {
     // function logic
}
```